GCP entire Bucket exclusion - do we pay for each file deletion?
I know we have to pay for each file operation when we delete individual or mass objects in a bucket.
I have a bucket with around 15 million objects.
Does anyone know if deleting the entire bucket is there a charge for each file inside the bucket?
https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/deleting-buckets

You will pay for the API call and, optionally, for early deletion (if you have a cold storage and you do not let enough time the file in)

One time-api call, right? So it should be much more efficient in term of costs then deleting one by one?

no, you need to delete all the objects to delete the buckets. If you are not in the hurry, set a lifecycle, and define a rule to delete the objects that have more than 1 day. The automatic process will delete the file for you and you do not pay for API calls (but it's not expensive the API call)
